# Injecting non-primative types without wrapping them in an inteface in StructureMap

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have a simple SM Registry where I am configuring all my instances of IDynamicValue. I have some contructor arguments that are non-primative types (in my case a DateTime and a Predicate Of T). Is there a way I can inject these without having to wrap them in a class with an interface (so they can be auto-wired). The following code snippet shows what I would like to accomplish:

```
ForRequestedType<IDynamicValue>().AddInstances(x =>
             {
                 x.OfConcreteType<DateTimeGenerator>().WithName("DateTime")
                     .WithCtorArg("keyName").EqualTo("DateTime")
                     .WithCtorArg("startDate").EqualTo(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))
                     .WithCtorArg("minuteIntervalDelta").EqualTo(60);

             });
```

That example runs but fails with the exception:

StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily System.DateTime

Thanks,
Nic

**EDIT:**

Freddy Rios solution worked perfect for what I needed. I am still curious if there is a method of doing this if I was auto-wiring some contructor arguments (hence couldn't use ConstructedBy())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already passing all the arguments to the constructor, you could use ConstructedBy instead:

```
x.ConstructedBy(y => new DateTimeGenerator(
          "DateTime", DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1), 60
         )
   ).WithName("DateTime");
```